# Display SVG with mm measures in browser with real life size

Tags: javascript, html, web, svg, cad

I have a SVG image that I would need to display in real life size. Currently my paths are already defined in mm like this :

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:lc="http://www.librecad.org" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1480.64944013mm" height="276.99494955mm" viewBox="0 0 1480.64944013 276.99494955">
<g lc:layername="0" lc:is_locked="false" lc:is_construction="false" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <path d="M1424.59844281,29.19495985 L0,29.19495985 L0,276.99494955 L1424.59844281,276.99494955 L1424.59844281,29.19495985 Z "/>
    <line x1="250.93711729" y1="206.68428137" x2="251.81394846" y2="209.84892956"/>
```

Can someone just give me some clue or direction on how can this be displayed on my browser in real mm ? That can be measured with a ruler

Comment: SVG and CSS [don't support real life units](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units), mainly because they don't really know how big the display is.

Comment: i don't think it is possible because every screen has different ppi

Answer (score 0):

Real life measurements are for printing purpose but for screen you need to convert them to pixel to work.

[Unit Converter](https://www.unitconverters.net/typography/millimeter-to-pixel-x.htm)